# EditText with textMultiLine not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, multiline

Here is my EditText. Why isn't allowing multiple lines?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtextDesigner"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:ems="10"
    android:lines="2"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:text=" "
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

I've also set it programmatically.

```
        edit_View.setSingleLine(false);
        edit_View.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
        edit_View.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why this isn't working.

Comment: I don't get it. All `EditText`s are **multiline** by default.

Comment: Try remove line:2 and the background

Comment: I removed ``edit_View.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);`` and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue very recently.  I found that setting the inputType programmaticly resets most options so you will have to set them after. I think changing your code to this may work:

```
edit_View.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
edit_View.setSingleLine(false);
edit_View.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
<EditText
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLength="255"
        android:id="@+id/etRemarks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />
```

Key attributes are:

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
android:maxLines="4". // to set the limit
android:lines="4" // to set the 4-liner appearance by default
```